# Are there any detailed studies on Phonology of Georgian language?

Tags: phonology, reference-request, georgian

As a native speaker of Georgian, I'm interested in learning more about Phonology of my native language.

Answer (score 3):

[This work](https://www.lotpublications.nl/Documents/063_fulltext.pdf) by Butskhrikidze is reasonably detailed though not comprehensive: you can follow the references therein to expand the coverage. I would also include Ritter "Georgian consonant clusters: The complexity is in the structure, not the melody", which was published later, but which is more a theoretical interpretation in a particular framework.